# Using the logic from one lambda within a second lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I've looked at the other questions around this and I just can't work out how to apply the answers to my particular situation.  Say you have a couple of models that look like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

public class Business
{
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to write a couple of different generic methods: one that gets the models using a provided Lambda that might look something like this:

```
GetWhere(p => p.PersonId == 1)
```

And one to get the models using a unique key - to make this flexible, I'd like to be able to specify the unique key using a Lambda:

```
GetByUniqueKey(p => p.PersonId, 1)
```

Or

```
GetByUniqueKey(b => b.BusinessId, 1)
```

Ideally `GetByUniqueKey` would just be a shorthand method to build up an expression to send to `GetWhere`, and then return the FirstOrDefault() result. But the logic to do this is completely escaping me. What I want to do:

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> GetWhere(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> whereExpression)
{
    // Get from DB using expression provided
}

public TModel GetByUniqueKey<TUniqueKey>(
         Expression<Func<TModel, TUniqueKey>> uniqueKeyProperty,
         TUniqueKey value)
{
    return GetWhere(m => uniqueKeyProperty(m) == value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**So I want to take the `uniqueKeyProperty` expression, invoke it on the supplied parameter somehow to get the property, and then *use that property* in the `whereExpression` expression.**

**A note on duplicate questions:**
I know this looks like a duplicate of other similar questions, but please note I have read those and I just can't figure out how to apply those answers to my specific use case.

**Some clarification in response to comments**:

Put simply, I want to do the following:

I want to take the Expression `p => p.PersonId` and the value 1, and generate a `whereExpression` that looks like this `p => p.PersonId == 1`. (Thanks @Rob)

Comment: Can you not just do `context.Set<TModel>().FirstOrDefault(whereExpression)` ?

Comment: In your example, I need "whereExpression" to contain the result of a second lambda.  Also I think you're using EF, which I'm not.

Comment: If you're querying the database, `whereExpression` can't have a result - it'll still be the expression, as we're comparing values on the row to something (and we haven't loaded the rows). Can you include code of how you were to load from the DB manually?

Comment: You're not really addressing the question at hand - the question is "Can I use the logic of one lambda in a second lambda, and if so, how?"

Comment: I'm focusing on it because the question `Can I use the logic of one lambda in a second lambda, and if so, how` doesn't really make sense. *how* do you want to use the lambda? `uniqueKeyProperty(m) == value` won't even compile, as it is. It's incredibly difficult to answer a question when you're not showing *how* you're going to be using it. In fact, you may be even to just write `GetByUniqueKey(p => p.PersonId == 1)` instead of `GetByUniqueKey(p => p.PersonId, 1)` - in which case the question is trivial, as it would simply call GetWhere(expr).FirstOrDefault().

Comment: In addition, your question might just be "How do I turn `p => p.PersonId, 1` into `p => p.PersonId == 1` with Expressions. If you hide information you're going to get a sub-par answer, if you even get an answer at all. And further, it depends on how `GetWhere` is using the expression. Is it passing in its own parameters, for example?

Comment: @Rob I have included examples of my intended usage, including an example of how I intend to use the logic of one lambda to select a property that is then tested in the second lambda.  I'm not sure what you mean when you talk about a lack of usage examples, I can only assume you've misunderstood my question, which may be my fault, but I can't see how to improve it.

Comment: Could you include a sample of how you would accomplish this query manually, using `GetWhere` ?

Comment: @Rob I want to take the Expression `p => p.PersonId` and the int 1, and generate a `whereExpression` that looks like this `p => p.PersonId == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a new expression from the key selector and value provided like so:

```
public TModel GetByUniqueKey<TUniqueKey>(
    Expression<Func<TModel, TUniqueKey>> uniqueKeySelector,
    TUniqueKey value)
{
    return GetWhere(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel,bool>>(
        Expression.MakeBinary(
            ExpressionType.Equal,
            uniqueKeySelector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TUniqueKey))),
        uniqueKeySelector.Parameters));
}
```

For querying by ID I wouldn't bother with this approach. Check out the other static methods on the [Expression class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @pmccloghrylaing, I've gone with this approach so that I can have a nice shortcut method for fetching a single item by any kind of unique identifier, without needing to FirstOrDefault it every time.  In my actual implementation I also have some checks to guarantee only a single result was found. Thanks again, your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As apparently you would like to implement some kind of polymorphism, one possibility would be to have `Person` and `Business` inherit from the same base class or inherit from the same interface and share an `Id` property. You could define

```
public class Identifiable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and make `Person` and `Business` inherit from in. Then the callback

```
Func<Identifiable,bool> = iIdentifiable => iIdentifiable.Id == 1
```

could be called for objects of both classes. However, the original classes would have to be changed for that approach to work.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a viable approach, but the code I provided was just one example, there are other uses for having this kind of flexibility so I'd still like to be able to combine these lambdas, if it's possible at all.